# Heroku Django request.POST giving wrong values

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have deployed an app in heroku build using django.In my django `views.py` iam getting some value using `request.POST` and storing in a `global` variable so that i can access that value in another function which is then rendered into the template.
Eveything worked fine on devolopment server but when i deployed it on heruko,`request.POST` is not retriving the correct value.

`views.py:`

```
serv='--'
def home(request):
global serv
if request.method=='POST':
    dayCheck.clear()
    serv=request.POST['service']
    return HttpResponseRedirect('func')

def func(request):
    global serv
    #Doing something,does not involve serv
    return render(request,'index.html',{'service':serv})
```

When i try to log `serv` in `home()` it gives correct value but different value in `func`
and the same is rendered,mostly it will be value which i previously clicked or sometimes it would be just `--` as declared.
Please help me!
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't use *global* variables: that is a *very* severe antipattern: the only persistent parts of a web server should be the database and some file (hosting) services. The webserver can run several concurrent Django servers to parallelize requests, furthermore a different user will use the *same* logic, so the global variable can be modified by a totally *different* user.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is there any way to pass that value to `func` without using gloal variable

Comment: yes, through URL parameters, the querystring, POST parameters, the database, session variables, and cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *don't*. Using global state in a webserver is a *very* very severe antipattern. Often later several Django processes will run to handle the requests concurrently: this means that the next request can be processed by a different Django process. Furthermore it is also possible that in between the request of a *different* user is processed.

Usually you pass data through the URL parameter, the querystring, the database, POST parameters, session variables and cookies (where session variables and cookies are usually not a good idea either, since these can easily collide with other views that store some state into the sessions or cookies).

You thus can thus for example make use of a URL parameter, where you map `func` to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('func/<path:param>/', views.func, name='func')
]
```

then you thus make a request with:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dayCheck.clear()
        serv = request.POST['service']
        return redirect('func', param=serv)

def func(request, param):
    # here param has the value for serv in the previous request
    return render(request,'index.html',{'service':serv})
```

since it will make a GET request to `func`, `func` is furthermore *not* allowed to make any changes to the entities either, since this is specified by the [HTTP specifications on *safe methods* [w3.org]](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1):

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods **SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval**. These methods ought to be considered "safe".

Comment: Hey i ran into a problem,earlier my `urls.py` it was `path('func/',views.func,name='func'),
path('func/func2',views.func2,name='func2')`,after your suugestion this not working,how to fix it

Comment: i tried giving `path('func/<str:param/func2/',views.func2,name='func2')` but it shows error

Comment: it gives error like this `The current path, func/service/func2 didn’t match any of these.`
Please help me with this one

Comment: @Arjun: you should work with a `<path:...>` URL parameter, and use a prefix that does not overlap with any other URL pattern.

Comment: Hey..its been long,but can we define a user object in django models and use getter and setters to get value instead of using url parameters